# How to create a spinning semi circle around text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a semi circle on the center of my page, which I want to be able to spin, I'm able to do some part of it by adjusting the width but I want a way to make it spin a complete 360degrees. If possible, I want to be able to accomplish it using only css, however if required I don't mind vanilla js (no Jquery).

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#txt {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#spinCircle {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 15%;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 150px 150px 0;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-style: none;
  /*background-color: black;*/
  animation: spinning infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    width: 50px
  }
  to {
    width: 0px;
    z-index: -5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="txt">Hello</div>
<div id="spinCircle" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#txt {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#spinCircle {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 15%;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 0 150px 150px 0;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-style: none;
  transform-origin: left;
  /*background-color: black;*/
  animation: spinning infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    z-index: -5;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="txt">Hello</div>
<div id="spinCircle" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's almost what I require, I want the semi circle to go a full 360deg which means the line has to come in front of the text as well. Also there seems to be one point in this animation when the line becomes invisible(at the back) I want a straight line to appear at that point, otherwise it doesn't look as smooth.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the semicircle to revolve around your  "hello" text. If so, you could use the `transform: rotateY()` style to spin your circle. If you do this, you can add your width to the circle div, as well as set the transform-origin to be the left-side of your element so that you rotate around the left-side of your semi-circle and not the center:

```
transform-origin: left;
 width: 50px;
```

See example below:

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#txt {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}

#spinCircle {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 15%;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 0 150px 150px 0;
  border-color: black;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  border-left-style: none;
  animation: spinning linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  transform-origin: left;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes spinning {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="txt">Hello</div>
<div id="spinCircle" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's almost what I require, I want the semi circle to go a full 360deg which means the line has to come in front of the text as well. Also there seems to be one point in this animation when the line becomes invisible(at the back) I want a straight line to appear at that point, otherwise it doesn't look as smooth.